# What is this and can dryer work without it?

Tags: dryer

[image]

Whirlpool dryer

It came out of dryer along with clothes.

Where does this go? Safe to operate dryer without it ?

Comment: look inside the dryer and see where it may have come from. It's likely that a sharp edge remains that could ruin your clothes

Comment: In the future, please use more than 10% of the image area to capture your subject. It's difficult to see what that is when it's so far away. :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the moisture sensor. It detects damp clothes and keeps the dryer running.  They are normally attached on the back of the drum. I have replaced the control boards in the past that have failed but never had the sensor come out. I know the dryers I have repaired worked on timer but not auto. I would look to see if it snaps in place with spade connections, if the electrical connections are fixed in place it would probably be ok to use but if there are any loose / flopping wires I would get it fixed prior to using it or other electrical problems may be caused.

Comment: The sensor is just two pieces of metal. Wet clothes contact the pieces of metal and conduct, telling the dryer that the clothes are still wet. With the sensor missing, no current will flow no matter how wet the clothes are and the dryer will stop too soon on auto. Most likely, no other harm will result. (But I'd definitely check for sharp edges that might damage your clothes or loose pieces that might get ripped off by moving clothes.)